# Trying to separate items in list by character but output returns multiple times

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to separate items in a list by character, and this is done but whenever i run the code it separates the items but shows them separated multiple times. How can I fix this?

I've already tried using range in a for function, but that hasn't worked. The only thing that gives an output is using

```
for character in x
```

My code:

```
def rle():
    askq = int(input("How many lines of RLE compressed data do you want to enter?"))
    if askq < 2:
        print("You must enter at least 2 lines of RLE compressed data.")
        rle()
    print("Please enter your RLE compressed data one line at a time")
    lines = []
    for i in range (0, askq):
        i = input("Which lines would you like to convert?")
        lines.append(i)
    num=0
    lines_input = [1,num]
    lines2 = []
    x = []
    for i in range(0,askq):
        num+=1
        if num in lines_input:
            x.append(lines[i])

        for x in lines:
            for character in x:
                lines2.append(character)
        print(lines2)




rle()
```

I expect the output of

```
lines2
```

to be

```
["0","1","d","6","1"," ","0","1","b"]
```

but instead i get

```
['0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b']
['0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b']
['0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 'd', '6', '1', ' ', '0', '1', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this update

```
def rle():
askq = int(input("How many lines of RLE compressed data do you want to enter?"))
if askq < 2:
    print("You must enter at least 2 lines of RLE compressed data.")
    rle()
print("Please enter your RLE compressed data one line at a time")
lines = []
for i in range (0, askq):
    i = input("Which lines would you like to convert?")
    lines.append(i)
new_list = []
for i in lines:
    new_list.extend(list(i))
print(new_list)

rle()
```

Comment: If when asked "how many lines do you want to enter?"
I put 3, and entered the RLE lines, how would I separate these 3 into 3 new lists? Thank you!

Comment: use: list.append(["your line goes here!"]), later iterate through that list